# How to authorize a security group rule which contains a variable?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I wrote a Cloud Formation template which starts up 12 servers.

I would like that the user-data script which runs upon the creation of a each new AWS EC2 instance to automatically add a rule to a security group.

If I'd know ahead the CIDR block then it would be as easy as running:

```
aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress \
    --group-id $opsSG \
    --ip-permissions '[{"IpProtocol": "-1", "IpRanges": [{"CidrIp": "172.53.0.0/16"}]}]' \
    --region us-west-2
```

But the CIDR block is held in a variable which is populated by the Cloud Formation stack creation.

So I've tried all kind of ways to add this rule but it always fails unless the CIDR block is set explicitly (as shown above).

Here's what I tried:

```
--ip-permissions '[{"IpProtocol": "-1", "IpRanges": [{"CidrIp": "$vpccidr"}]}]' \
--region us-west-2
```

And that's the error I got:

```
An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress operation: CIDR block $vpccidr is malformed
```

More tries:

```
echo """'[{\"IpProtocol\": \"-1\", \"IpRanges\": [{\"CidrIp\": \"$(echo $vpccidr)\"}]}]'""" > /tmp/1
```

and then:

```
aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress \
    --group-id $opsSG \
    --ip-permissions $(cat /tmp/1) \
    --region us-west-2

aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress \
    --group-id $opsSG \
    --ip-permissions '[{"IpProtocol": "-1", "IpRanges": [{"CidrIp": "$(echo $vpccidr)"}]}]' \
    --region us-west-2

aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress \
    --group-id $opsSG \
    --cli-input-json file:///tmp/1.json \
    --region us-west-2

Error parsing parameter 'cli-input-json': Invalid JSON: No JSON object could be decoded
JSON received: '[{"IpProtocol": "-1", "IpRanges": [{"CidrIp": "172.53.0.0/16"}]}]'
```

It doesn't matter what I try, it keeps failing adding the rule to the security group.

Any ideas?

Comment: Where does 172.53.0.0/16 come from? Is that the CIDR of a VPC that the same Cloudformation template is creating? Also, why do you want each EC2 instance to inject itself into a security group, rather than simply adding all the new instances into a security group within the template and then configuring the target SG to allow ingress from the new instance SG?

Comment: Only one instance out of the 12 is modifying the security group. The CIDR is inherited from the stack creation as a parameter of the stack. The reason that these configurations happen in the user-data and not from the CF template, is because in the user-data I create a vpc peering across regions (CF doesn't support cross region vpc peering yet, just the cli), and then I create the routing rules and next the security groups

Comment: You can take a look in the template: https://github.com/geek-kb/DevopsStuff/blob/master/CloudFormation/CloudFormation_example_v1.template --> the vpccidr variable can be found under the bastion launch configuration block.